# Row won't add to the end my JTable using vectors

Tags: java, swing, vector, jtable

I'm creating a Swing Application for work and I'm having issues with my JTable.

The process is to check to see if a file exist and if it does, retrieve the information from the file and populate the JTable.  This works fine.

I enter data into my textfields, select from dropdown box and when I click on the save button, I write the information to the file (which gets completed with no issue) and after the file is created, I would like to have the row added to my the end of the table.  This is where I'm having issues.

I end up calling the addRow method in the OutputTable my passing the data from what the user has entered.  The data is stored in the vector properly as you can see here:

```
d1 is[999999999, 27-May-2016, asdfasdf, OCOB, UA2, 1, asdf,     sadsadfasdf, IU2, 1, 28-May-2016, In Progress]
d2 is[999999999, 27-May-2016, asdfasdf, OCOB, UA2, 1, asdf,     sadsadfasdf, IU2, 1, 28-May-2016, In Progress]
```

But my `dtm.addRow(data)` won't add the row to the table.

Can someone help?

This is my class that retrieves the data from the file to populate the table at the beginning of my application.  Action is performed by a button.

My addRow method is in this class.

```
public class OutputTable {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static void populateTable(Vector data){

        Vector columnName = new Vector(12);

        columnName.addElement("ID");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>DATE <BR/>Retrieve");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>Name of <BR/>Module");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>Type of <BR/>Module");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>Environment <BR/>retrieve from");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>Stage <BR/>retrieve from");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>Working <BR/>location");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>Description <BR/>of changes");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>Environment <BR/>moved to");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>Stage <BR/>move to");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>Date of the <BR/>endevor");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>Current <BR/>Work <BR/>Status");

        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnName);

        final JTable table = new JTable();

        table.setModel(dtm);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.getTableHeader().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(scrollPane.getWidth(),60));
        scrollPane.setViewportBorder(UIManager.getBorder("Table.scrollPaneBorder"));
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 425, 875, 195);

        EndevorChanges.frmEndevorChanges.getContentPane().add(scrollPane); 

}

    public static void addRow(String UserID, String DateRtrv, String ModRtrv, String ModType, String EnvFrom, String StgFrom, String WrkngLct, String Desc, String EnvTo, String StgTo, String DateTo, String WrkSts) {

        System.out.println("Im inside the addrow method.");

        Vector<Vector<String>> data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
        Vector<String> d = new Vector<String>();
        Vector columnName = new Vector(12);
        String[] strngArray = {UserID, DateRtrv, ModRtrv, ModType, EnvFrom, StgFrom, WrkngLct, Desc, EnvTo, StgTo, DateTo, WrkSts};

    /*  columnName.addElement("ID");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>DATE <BR/>Retrieve");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>Name of <BR/>Module");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>Type of <BR/>Module");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>Environment <BR/>retrieve from");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>Stage <BR/>retrieve from");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>Working <BR/>location");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>Description <BR/>of changes");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>Environment <BR/>moved to");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>Stage <BR/>move to");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>Date of the <BR/>endevor");
        columnName.addElement("<HTML>Current <BR/>Work <BR/>Status");
        */
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnName);

        JTable table = new JTable();

        //table.setModel(dtm);

        System.out.println("the data is: " + data.toString());

        for (int lmnts = 0; lmnts < 12; lmnts++){
            d.add(strngArray[lmnts]);
            System.out.println("element" + lmnts + " value is: " + strngArray[lmnts]);
            System.out.println("d1 is" + d);
        }
        data.add(d);

        System.out.println("d2 is" + d);

        dtm.addRow(data);
        //dtm.insertRow(4, data);

        dtm.fireTableDataChanged();

        table.repaint();

        System.out.println("at the end of the method");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your row is in fact being added to a JTable's TableModel just fine, but the problem is that it's being added to the *wrong* JTable. Current problems that are immediately apparent:

```
public class OutputTable {

    public static void populateTable(Vector data){

        // .... code removed for brevity's sake

        // you create a *local* DefaultTableModel variable here. It is only visible within this method
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnName);

        // Likewise, this JTable variable is *local*
        final JTable table = new JTable();

        // .....
    }

    public static void addRow(String UserID, String DateRtrv, String ModRtrv, String ModType, String EnvFrom, String StgFrom, String WrkngLct, String Desc, String EnvTo, String StgTo, String DateTo, String WrkSts) {

        // .....

        // this guy is a completely new unique DefaultTableModel object, again placed
        // within a local variable, one only seen within this method.
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnName);

        // and a new local JTable
        JTable table = new JTable();


        // here you "repaint" this JTable, and it's not even displayed in your GUI
        table.repaint();

    }
}
```

- You're declaring your variables and assigning your tablemodel and your JTable within a method, meaning these variables are **only** visible within this method and nowhere else.
- You're then creating a **new** JTable and new table model within a separate method, updating the model, and expecting the visualized table (a completely separate and unique object) to be magically updated -- not going to happen.
- You're over-using statics by doing any of this within static methods.

Suggestions:

- Create private instance JTable and DefaultTableModel variables.
- Create objects and assign them to these variables, either in a constructor or in an instance method.
- When you need to update the model, use the variable above, and add a row. Problem solved!
- Note that a **BAD** solution is to try to use static variables. Seriously, don't go there.

Also:

- Try to get most all your code out of the static realm and into the instance realm.
- The main method should be short, and should only be used to create your key objects, and then start them running, and that's it.
- You appear to be using null layouts and `setBounds(...)`. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.
- You're mixing *model* and *view* code in dangerous and confusing ways. If you can separate these guys cleanly, you'll have a much easier time debugging and enhancing your program. For instance the table model creation and modification code should be separate from the code that adds JTables and JScrollPanes to the GUI.

Comment: thanx will go and modify my logic